# Declaration on ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm working on some code, and I came across the following situation inside an archive .js --

```
(function(Ext) { ..."Here have 2 Ext.Define"... })(Ext);
```

This code runs normally, but i can't find because the declaration is like that, what is the difference of use simply 2 Ext.Define, the guy who did that code don't work here anymore, but my colleagues said that according to him this is more faster to render, this information proceeds? and if it is, what kind of situations i can use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an example of a **self executing function**. 
There are some situations when developers use self invoking functions (also known as ***anonymous*** functions), like for example when you want an auto-run capability to your app.

My guess is that the previous developer, that worked in your project, wanted just this. Execute the function as soon as it was defined, as some sort of auto-run mechanism.

Also you could use a self invoking function when for example you want to regularly updates a webpage, by using for example **setInterval**.

```
 (function refreshDB(){
      setTimeout(refreshDatabase, 60000);
   })()
```

A self executing function is executed as soon as it is defined.

You can look at it this way:

- `function(Ext) { ..."Here have 2 Ext.Define"... }` represents the definition/declaration of the function, which takes one argument `Ext`
- `(function declaration)(arguments)`, in your case the arguments is only one, namely an object called `Ext`. This is simply the convention on how to declare and execute a self invoking function in JavaScript.

Also, the following syntax:
      `(function(arg){console.log(arg)})('Hello World!')`
has the same outcome as
     `! function(arg){console.log(arg)}('Hello World!')`
which is just another way of declaring a self-invoking function.